# Password does not match with hash algorithm (SQL Server)

Tags: php, sql-server, passwords, password-hash

I got a problem with SQL Server. My Task is it to realize a simple SQL Serverbased usersystem with PHP. The databases are also used by a MMORPG so I am not allowed to change the database structure or hashing alogrithms. The real cause of my problem is, that the password is hashed by the following alogrithm

```
HashBytes('MD5', REVERSE(UPPER(@ID)) + @PW)
```

I created a test user called test123 and pw hallo123 what conforms the password hash "0x7CEE495091E11FF9560D3D01651333220000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

up to this point everything should be clear. Well but when I try to fetch the data by a query I get no results. I ran this query:

```
mssql_query("SELECT * FROM [DB_Member].[dbo].[Member] WHERE ID = 'test123' AND PW = HashBytes('MD5', REVERSE(UPPER('test123')) + 'hallo123')");
```

Which returns no result. But if I directly run this query

```
mssql_query("SELECT * FROM [DB_Member].[dbo].[Member] WHERE ID = 'test123' AND PW = 0x7CEE495091E11FF9560D3D01651333220000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000);
```

I get the data without any problems

I'm grappling with this now for about eight hours but I can't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have a closer look at your data types. My guess is that the variables @ID and @PW is a char data type where the hash is generated. When you try the query, inserting 'test123' and 'hallo123', you need to add spaces after so they match whatever char(?) data type they were in the routine that created the hash.

Here is an example illustrating the difference in using char and varchar data types.

Using char

```
declare @PW char(25)
declare @ID char(25)

set @PW = 'hallo123'
set @ID = 'test123'

select (HashBytes('MD5', REVERSE(UPPER(@ID)) + @PW))
```

Hash result

```
0x9F1E0132F198216841E2608901D27115
```

Using varchar

```
declare @PW varchar(25)
declare @ID varchar(25)

set @PW = 'hallo123'
set @ID = 'test123'

select (HashBytes('MD5', REVERSE(UPPER(@ID)) + @PW))
```

Hash result

```
0x870B01D196916AFA88EBC900BE5395BE
```

The hashes clearly does not match.

The reason you have a bunch of zeros after your hash is because the hash is stored in a binary(60) field. HashBytes returns a VarBinary but that is not the reason for the query to fail. SQL Server does some kind of conversion when comparing binary with VarBinary.

Comment: Great Answer, thank you! Is there a way to take a look at the query exactely the way theserver recieves it? Then I could see which hash is being generated. Thanks

Comment: @Thomas - You can use SQL Server Profiler to look at what is sent to the server when you set the password. Setup a trace and start it just before you change the password and then turn it off as soon as possible after. Then you *only* need to read through the log and look for the statement that changes the password and look at what the parameters contain. The example I gave was that they where padded with spaces. They could very well be padded with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that whatever language you're using is encoding it strangely?  What if you pull up a SQL profiler and look at the query that's being sent to see if you can spot the differences?

Answer (score 0):

When I run `SELECT HashBytes('MD5', REVERSE(UPPER('test123')) + 'hallo123')`, I get the result 0x870B01D196916AFA88EBC900BE5395BE. Are you sure your hash creation is correct, and that you used the correct ID and password when creating the test user?